# How to build delayed loop animation with two different objects consecutively?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to build an infinite animation which will stop at the end of each loop.

Here is what I have so far, but `animation-delay` is only working at the beginning, it doesn't work at the end in each turn.

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes ani-a {
    0% { transform: translateY(50px); opacity: 0; }
    50% { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 1; }
    75% { transform: translateY(50px); opacity: 0; }
    100% { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 1; }
}
.a {
 opacity: 1;
  animation: ani-a 6s infinite;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes ani-b {
    0% { transform: translateY(50px); opacity: 1; }
    50% { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 0; }
    75% { transform: translateY(50px); opacity: 1; }
    100% { transform: translateY(0px); opacity: 0; }
}
.b {
 opacity: 0;
  animation: ani-b 6s infinite;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a">A</span>
<span class="b">B</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had mentioned in comments to an earlier post of yours (on a similar topic), the `animation-delay` property **does not add** a delay automatically between iterations (or, in other words at the end of each iteration). It works only for the first iteration. If you want to add a delay between each iteration then you should use dummy keyframes in between (along with `animation-delay` for your case).

In the code given in question the below is what happens:

- Total animation duration is 6s.
- Specified keyframes are 50%, 75% and 100%. That is, at 3s, 4.5s and 6s mark of the animation there is a change from one state to another for each of the two animations.

For a delay to be present at the start and end of the animation, the following changes should be done:

- Retain the `animation-delay` setting to introduce a 6s delay at the start of first iteration.
- Change the animation duration to 12s. 12s because your actual animation is for 6s and there is a need for a 6s delay at end of each iteration.
- Modify the keyframes to be at 25%, 37.5% and 50% because they correspond to 3s, 4.5s and 6s like in your original snippet.
- For 50% and 100% of the animation, do not change states (that is, apply the same setting). This means that for the last 50% of the animation duration (which would be 6s), the `span` would hold its state and thus give the illusion of a delay.

Below is a sample snippet with the above changes done.

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
}
@keyframes ani-a {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.a {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: ani-a 12s infinite;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
@keyframes ani-b {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.b {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: ani-b 12s infinite;
  animation-delay: 6s;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="a">A</span>
<span class="b">B</span>
```

Comment: this animation stucks /:

Comment: @BarlasApaydin: Did not understand what you mean by stucks. I am using Chrome v38 where it works fine and so should work in other versions also.

Comment: @BarlasApaydin: Glad that I could help but I am still worried about that sad smiley. Were you able to get it to work as you intended or is still not behaving as per your expectation? If it doesn't, clarify a bit more on what you expect and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: mate i could not manage to work this thing on my website, http://www.digicots.com/ check out the astronaut on the landing page. its loop animation works well but animation-delay not works on each loop /:

Comment: @BarlasApaydin: Sorry to be blunt but the delay won't happen unless you make all the changes that I have mentioned in my answer. I just checked your website and you have not done the changes that I have mentioned to the `keyframes`.